# Windows 11 TaskBar API to add or remove icons?

Tags: winapi, taskbar, windows-11

Does Windows 11 have an API or other method to programmably add/remove icons from the taskbar?

Comment: If you mean to "pin" icons to the taskbar, then [no](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20141230-00/?p=43273).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ITaskbarList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-itaskbarlist) interface has [`AddTab()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-itaskbarlist-addtab) and [`DeleteTab()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-itaskbarlist-deletetab) methods.